# displaying sql all table and using like navigation for show columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display all table list from a proper database and want to show list of table in link or navigation format when I click on proper table name then I can see all column of that table.

I can display all list of table by this code:

```
mysql_select_db("dj", $con);

$result = mysql_query("show tables"); t
while($table = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 

    echo($table[0] . "<BR>");
}
```

By this code I'm sucess to display all table from a database but I want code for display all rows of proper table where table name will be show like link or navigation.

Answer (score 0):

1. [`SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-columns.html) will give you column list for a specific table
2. [Anchor tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/the-a-element.html#the-a-element) that might look like this `<a href="columns.php?table=tablename">tablename</a>` will help you create your links
3. [`$_GET['table']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) will allow you to get a parameter passed with a url

Now, how to query the db and traverse the resultset you already know, therefore you just need **to put some effort** and glue it all together.

> And please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are
>   [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use  [prepared
>   statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)
>   or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: NOT SOLVED BRO,I WANT TO USE TABLE LIKE A FOLDER AND TABLES ROW AS FOLDER CONTENT.  OR SUPPOSE I WANT TO DISPLAY ALL MOVIE LIST AS PROPER (TABLE) AND ROW OF THAT TABLE WILL BE SONGS OF THAT MOVIE.CAN ANYONE TELL ME HOW I WILL DO THIS

Comment: still waiting for some one reply plz help me.